# How can I use scroll to show all combobox on form C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have use code to display Combobox on a formChild

```
ComboBox[] cbbItem = new ComboBox[20];
for( int i=0; i>20; i++)
{
 cbbItem[i] = new ComboBox();
 cbbItem[i].Location = new Point(5, (i * 50+10));
 cbbItem[i].BringToFront(); 
 this.Controls.Add(cbbItem[i]);

}
```

This is a sample for my code create Combobox.

And I want to put these forms in a panel of the parent form.
But according to my calculation, I need 20 comboboxes on 1 form, they are arranged in a vertical column, and their total height is about more than 1000, but my form can only expand to 800 max, when I run the test. In visual app, scroll can only let me drag to 9th combobox.
Form can't increase height any more.
I have tried to find a way from many sources, but it doesn't work.
Hope if someone can give me a solution.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Use a FlowLayoutPanel, so you don't need any calculation (the child Controls layout is automatic) and set its `AutoScroll` property to `true`

Comment: @Jimi thank, i will try it with FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Panel control in form, Set Panel properties `AutoScroll=true`. and edit your code:

```
ComboBox[] cbbItem = new ComboBox[20];
for( int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
 cbbItem[i] = new ComboBox();
 cbbItem[i].Location = new Point(5, (i * 50+10));
 cbbItem[i].BringToFront(); 
 panel1.Controls.Add(cbbItem[i]);
}
```

**Note:** Condition of for loop is `i<20` not `i>20`. good luck.

Comment: thanks for answer, I was try like you tell before, but i just can scroll it to 13th comboboxs. I think because I add that form to a parent panel, and it is affected by the height of the panel